# How to add @import "some.css" and not have it processed by Sass

Tags: sass, gulp-sass, libsass

I have a scss file in which I do not want sass to process an @import statement as it will be processed by this postcss module https://github.com/postcss/postcss-import

How can I do this using gulp-sass?

Comment: Sass does not process .css files at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but if you `@import` a `.css` file the `@import` statement will remain intact in the resulting `.css` file. You could then run other tasks on the resulting `.css` file. This is as opposed to calling `@import` on a `.scss` or `.sass` file which Sass will then attempt to compile.

Comment: Postcss requires it to be as such `@import "foo.css";` where as sass converts it to a `@import url(....css);`

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Sass will compile `@import “some.css”` to `@import url(....css);`

Why don't you use Postcss (and neccessary plugins) to compile your .scss file and that way postcss-import can deal with the `@import`.